# Athena/Presto data discovery query to recommend JSON schema?

Tags: amazon-athena, presto

I have an Athena table (`raw`) with just one column (`json`).

I have the following query which outputs the frequencies of json keys:

```
SELECT key, count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT map_keys(cast(json_parse(json) AS map(varchar, json))) AS keys
  FROM raw
)
CROSS JOIN UNNEST (keys) AS t (key)
GROUP BY key
```

How can I extend this query so that it'll tell me whether a particular key has values with any non-numeric characters?

[failed attempts deleted after I found answer]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works:

```
SELECT k, count(*) as isPresent, sum(isNumber) as isNumber, 
          count(*)-sum(isNumber) as notIsNumber from (
               with dataset as (SELECT 
                   cast(json_parse(json) AS map(varchar, varchar)) as kv FROM raw)
               SELECT t.k, t.v, 
                      IF(TRY(cast(t.v as double)) is null, 0, 1) as isNumber 
               from dataset cross join unnest(kv) as t(k, v)
) group by k
```